# Creating dashboards using plotly without sending data to plotly server

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook, plotly

From what I understand ( and tried ) ,we can create charts offline using plotly on a jupyter notebook using

```
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
```

Now as per the example to use the dashboard api  on the plotly's website , in the end it returns a url to the dashboard you just created which is uploaded to your plotly account . What I want to know is ,how to create dashboards without sending it to my plotly account .

Comment: did you tried using `plotly.offline.iplot` when create a plot? If I am correctly understand, that `s solution for your problem